# Conformal transformations that preserves the string boundary condition

Tags: string-theory, coordinate-systems, conformal-field-theory, boundary-conditions

I am currently reading 't Hooft's lecture notes on string theory [[1](https://webspace.science.uu.nl/%7Ehooft101/lectures/stringnotes.pdf)]. I am trying to show that given the world sheet metric $h_{ab}(\tau,\sigma)$ and the boundary condition for closed string
$$
X^\mu(\tau, \sigma) = X^\mu(\tau, \sigma + 2\pi)
$$
we can always find some coordinate transformation $\tau, \sigma \to \tilde{\tau}, \tilde{\sigma}$ so that the boundary condition still has the form
$$
X^\mu(\tilde{\tau}, \tilde{\sigma}) = X^\mu(\tilde{\tau}, \tilde{\sigma} + 2\pi)
$$
while the world sheet metric becomes conformal, i.e.,
$$
\tilde{h}_{ab}=\eta_{ab}e^{\omega(\tilde{\tau},\tilde{\sigma})}
$$
In the notes (on the bottom page 11), it was suggested that we can always first go to some conformal gauge, and then use transformation of the form
$$
\sigma^\pm\to f^\pm(\sigma^\pm), \quad \sigma^\pm = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\sigma \pm \tau)
$$
to transform the boundary conditions to the desired form while keeping the conformal gauge. But I am having a hard time to find such transformations. Any help or suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why we can always find a diffeomorphism $\sigma^\alpha\rightarrow\tilde{\sigma}^\alpha(\sigma^0,\sigma^1)$ with $\sigma^\alpha\in\{\tau,\sigma\}$, that preserves the form of the boundary conditions for the closed string is due to the fact that the Nambu-Goto action is invariant under diffeomorphisms on the worldsheet. Consider in general the map$$X:\Sigma\rightarrow\mathbb{M}\quad\text{with}\quad(\sigma^0,\sigma^1)\mapsto X^\mu(\sigma^0,\sigma^1).$$Here $\Sigma$ is your worldsheet and $\mathbb{M}$ is your spacetime manifold. Then the Nambu-Goto action is given by$$S[X]=-T\int_\Sigma d^2\sigma\sqrt{|\det{(\partial_\alpha X^\mu\partial_\beta X^\nu)}|}.$$Here we are taking $\sigma^0\in(-\infty,\infty)$ and $\sigma^1\in[0,2\pi]$. Now we show that $S[X]$ is invariant under orientation preserving reparameterizations of the worldsheet $\Sigma$, of the form$$\sigma^\alpha\rightarrow\tilde{\sigma}^\alpha(\sigma^0,\sigma^1)\quad\text{where}\quad\det{\left(\frac{\partial\tilde{\sigma}^\alpha}{\partial\sigma^\beta}\right)}>0.$$Let$$J=\left(\frac{\partial\tilde{\sigma}^\alpha}{\partial\sigma^\beta}\right).$$We then have that $d^2\tilde{\sigma}=|\det{(J)}|d^2\sigma=(\det{(J)})d^2\sigma$ since $J>0$ by assumption. We can now write$$\frac{\partial X^\mu}{\partial\tilde{\sigma}^\alpha}=\frac{\partial\sigma^\gamma}{\partial\tilde{\sigma}^\alpha}\frac{\partial X^\mu}{\partial\sigma^\gamma}=J^{-1}\frac{\partial X^\mu}{\partial\sigma^\gamma}.$$Now if we write$$g:=g_{\alpha\beta}=\frac{\partial X^\mu}{\partial\sigma^\alpha}\frac{\partial X^\mu}{\partial\sigma^\beta}\quad\text{and}\quad \tilde{g}:=\tilde{g}_{\alpha\beta}=\frac{\partial X^\mu}{\partial\tilde{\sigma}^\alpha}\frac{\partial X^\mu}{\partial\tilde{\sigma}^\beta},$$we see that$$\tilde{g}=(J^{-1})^\text{T}gJ^{-1}\implies|\det{(\tilde{g})}|=|\det{\left((J^{-1})^\text{T}gJ^{-1}\right)}|=|\det{(g)}|(\det{(J)})^{-2}$$and thus$$\sqrt{|\det{(g)}|}=(\det{(J)})^{-1}\sqrt{|\det{(g)}|}.$$Putting everything together, we see that$$\tilde{S}[X]=-T\int_{\Sigma}d^2\tilde{\sigma}\sqrt{|\det{(\tilde{g}_{\alpha\beta})}|}=-T\int_\Sigma d^2\sigma(\det{(J)})(\det{(J)})^{-1}\sqrt{|\det{(g_{\alpha\beta})}|}=S[X].$$So as we can see, $S[X]$ is indeed invariant under a reparameterization of $\Sigma$. Now the boundary conditions for the closed string (as well as all the others), come about by considering the variations $X\rightarrow X+\delta X$ of the worldsheet. Since the Nambu-Goto action is invariant under reparameterizations $\sigma^\alpha\rightarrow\tilde{\sigma}^\alpha(\sigma^0,\sigma^1)$, so are the boundary conditions (since we are free to reparametrize and then compute the boundary conditions). So if we have$$X^\mu(\sigma^0,\sigma^1+2\pi)=X^\mu(\sigma^0,\sigma^1)\quad\text{then we also have}\quad X^\mu(\tilde{\sigma}^0,\tilde{\sigma}^1+2\pi)=X^\mu(\tilde{\sigma}^0,\tilde{\sigma}^1).$$

Comment: I don't understand "so are the boundary conditions (since we are free to reparametrize and then compute the boundary conditions)". It's not obvious to me that you can find such re-parametrization that preserves the conformal gauge while bringing the boundary condition to the desired form.

Comment: The boundary conditions come from the Nambu-Goto action, so you can reparametrise the action and then find the boundary conditions. Additionally, you can instead consider the Polyakov action (worldsheet action), which is invariant under conformal transformations and reparametrisation. You can vary the Polyakov action with respect to the string coordinates and the induced metric to work out the boundary conditions as before. The symmetries of the Polyakov action can be used to fix the induced metric and get the conformal gauge, arriving to the desired result.

Comment: I know it should be doable but my question is about explicit construction of such conformal transformation. I understand the string action is invariant under local parameterization and Weyl transformation.